# Convert S3 object as pyspark dataframe with Boto3 : TypeError: path can be only string, list or RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

I am reading S3(minio) object and trying to convert it into pyspark dataframe. I am trying this.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
s3 = boto3.client('s3',endpoint_url='Endpoint URL',aws_access_key_id='key',aws_secret_access_key='secret key',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),region_name='us-east-1')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket_name', Key='file_name')
df = spark.read.option('header','true').option('inferSchema','true').csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

But I am getting the below error -

```
df = spark.read.option('header','true').option('inferSchema','true').csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
'TypeError: path can be only string, list or RDD\n'])
```

Same code works fine for reading the python 3 pandas dataframe but does not work for pyspark dataframe
Below works fine -

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

Please help